# javascript random flashing words

Tags: javascript, random, colors, cpu-word

Here's a fun little script I'm trying to make. Flash words from an array with random colors from another array. (I'm mostly thinking about having a moving bg type deal.)

I'm having problems with creating some sort of loop to cause the words to "flash/change" so far all it does is change on page reload.

****new**** 
Well I changed it so now it is just one function... and it WORKS!! but it seems that it uses the browsers memory or something and crashes.... oops... is there a clear memory or something for javascript that I should use??

```
<html>

<head>
<style>

body

{
  color:black;
}

#quotes 
   {

   }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function showQuote() 
{

pickWords =

[
  "Hi!",
  "Welcome!",
  "Hello!"
]

var word22 = pickWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*pickWords.length)];


pickColors =

[
  "#aa2233",
  "#00cc44",
  "#F342AA"
]

var Color22 = pickColors[Math.floor(Math.random()*pickColors.length)];


var Top22 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*800));
var Left22 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*800));

var style33 = '<h4 style="padding-bottom:0px; padding-top:'+Top22+'px; padding-left:'+Left22+'px; font-size: 2.3em; color:'+Color22+';">';
var style34 = '</h4>';

var finWord22 = style33 + word22 + style34;


var duration = 400;  




     document.getElementById("quotes").innerHTML=finWord22;
setInterval('showQuote()',duration);

}


onload = function()
{
showQuote();
}



</script>

<div id="quotes"></div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to 'pickword' inside the showQuote() function.

Right now, you are picking a word onload, and use that word on every timeout.

Wrap your whole code into a function and call that function on load.

```
function ShowQuote(){
    //...
    setTimeout(ShowQuote, duration);
}

ShowQuote();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling setinterval in the function, where as you should use settimeout. That should help you out with the crashing :P